# Add space between text and line in <li><a> element

Tags: html

I've looked at various solutions in regards to this question, but they don't seem to apply.

This is my simple HTML code:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="games.php">Games</a></li>
<li><a href="trivia.php">Trivia</a></li>
</ul>
```

How do I increase the space between the text and the line underneath it?

Answer (score 1):

Use `<br>` or `line-height` css rules or simply do that to `<li>` css:

```
li
{ display:block;
  height:XXXX;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css:

```
li {
    margin-bottom:5px;
}
```

Change `5px` accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

There are actually three or more ways.. here are the best three:

**1.** make 
 that will make a brake between them, like you just hitted enter key.
**2.** You can use `li{padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;}` or just in html using

ul>
    li style="padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;">Home

You know what I mean, I cant write it correctly, **cause it will do ul in that post..**

**now**, the third should be same as padding, but use "margin" instead